# HTML form in React with submission and validation outside of form

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am trying to create an html form in react. This works, I can also submit it outside the form. By a button with input-type submit and the same id as the form. Only before the post action is executed I would check the form for completeness.

This is my current function that checks if the fields are filled in:

```
 checkLabels(){

    console.log('wordt gecheckt')
    
      if(this.state.name == ''){
          this.setState({
              errorMessage: 'Vul a.u.b. een naam in.'
          })
      }else if(this.state.email == ''){
        this.setState({
            errorMessage: 'Het e-mail adres is niet ingevult.'
        })
      }else if(this.state.postal == ''){
        this.setState({
            errorMessage: 'Er is geen postcode ingevult.'
        })
      }
      else if(this.state.number == ''){
        this.setState({
            errorMessage: 'Er is geen huisnummer ingevult.'
        })
      }else if(this.state.city == ''){
        this.setState({
            errorMessage: 'Er is geen woonplaats ingevult.'
        })
      }
  }
```

This is my form:

```
            <Col sm={4} className="h3-blue-left data-section">
                <h3>Gegevens en bezorgadres</h3>
                <form  method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/payment/" id="hook-form" onSubmit={this.checkLabels}>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Naam *" value={this.state.name} onChange={event => this.setState({ name: event.target.value, errorMessage:''})}/>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail adres*" value={this.state.email} onChange={event => this.setState({ email: event.target.value, errorMessage:''})}/>
                <input type="text" name="postal_code" placeholder="Postcode *" value={this.state.postal} onChange={event => this.setState({ postal: event.target.value, errorMessage:''})}/>
                <input type="text" name="house_number" placeholder="Huisnummer *" value={this.state.number} onChange={event => this.setState({ number: event.target.value, errorMessage:''})}/>
                <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Woonplaats *" value={this.state.city} onChange={event => this.setState({ city: event.target.value, errorMessage:''})}/>
                <input type="hidden" name="booklet" placeholder="boekjes" value={this.state.amountBooks} onChange={event => this.setState({ booklet: event.target.value, errorMessage:''})}/>
                <input type="hidden" name="voucher" placeholder="voucher" value={this.state.amountVouchers} onChange={event => this.setState({ voucher: event.target.value, errorMessage:''})}/>
                <label className="checkbox-picoo">Ja, schrijf mij ook in voor de nieuwsbrief <input type="checkbox"onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} defaultChecked={this.state.checked}/></label>
                <span className="required-items">* De gegevens met een sterretje zijn verplicht.</span>
            
                </form>
            </Col>
```

And this is my button outside the form:

```
 <button type="submit" form="hook-form">Bevestig gegevens & betaal </button>
```

I'm in the process of learning React so that's why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using state management, you can actually just remove the `action` from the form and just trigger the function on `onSubmit` you can then use `fetch` or [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) to perform POST request:

(sample code)

```
<form  id="hook-form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Naam *" value={this.state.name} onChange={event => this.setState({ name: event.target.value, errorMessage:''})}/>
</form>
```

then on `onSubmit` (assuming that you are not using class):

```
const onSubmit = () => {
 if(this.state.name == ''){
     this.setState({
        errorMessage: 'Vul a.u.b. een naam in.'
     })
 }
 // other checking logic

 // perform POSt
  fetch.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/payment/", {
     params: {
        name: this.state.name,
        // other fields
     }

  })
}
```